# unexpected strict mode reserved word while connecting mongodb from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have installed mongodb 3.4 and nodejs v0.12.2. When i was trying to connect mongodb from nodejs script `var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;`
It shows

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vishnuprasath.r\nodej
odules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\index.js:19:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Please help me to fix the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 99% it wont help but try change you variable name  var m = require('mongodb').MongoClient  also try do it in a new project see if it comes from anther place of the app or not

Comment: same issue persists